# "may not respond to 'initWithStyle:'" warning in Xcode 4.2

Tags: xcode, warnings, xcode4.2

I have been using [CPLockController](https://github.com/haroldthehungry/CPLockController) Class happily for quite a while. But since upgraded to Xcode 4.2, I have been getting the following warning:

```
'CPLockController' may not respond to 'initWithStyle:'
```

wherever this line is in the code:

```
CPLockController *lockController = [[CPLockController alloc]initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)CPLockControllerTypeAuth];
```

The implementation in CPLockController.m file is:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(CPLockControllerStyle)theStyle {
    if(self == [super init]){
        self.style = theStyle;
        self.retry = NO;
        self.tempString = [NSMutableString string];
        self.hideCode = YES;
    }

    return self;
}
```

and type definition of CPLockControllerStyle:

```
typedef enum {
CPLockControllerTypeAuth,
CPLockControllerTypeSet
} CPLockControllerStyle;
```

I even created an issue in github, but no reply up till now!

Please guide... thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That’s because the developer hasn’t declared `-initWithStyle:` in the class declaration. If you inspect [CPLockController.h](https://github.com/haroldthehungry/CPLockController/blob/master/Classes/CPLockController.h), `-initWithStyle:` is not there.

I’m not sure why the developer hasn’t done this (maybe he’s forgotten it, in which case you should file a bug), but you can easily add the declaration to CPLockController.h as follows:

```
@interface CPLockController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
    // Bunch of ivars
}

// Bunch of properties

- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title;
- (id)initWithStyle:(CPLockControllerStyle)theStyle; // <-- add this line
@end
```

Comment: Thx... but now the warning changes to `warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'UITableViewStyle' to different enumeration type 'CPLockControllerStyle' [-Wconversion,3]`

Comment: @Tajar That’s because you’ve explicitly cast it to `(UITableViewStyle)`. Remove that cast.

Comment: Thanks! Super expert helping a super noob!